# 'cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful' in time series

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to denoise a time-series data using smooth.spline in R. Eventhough I am pretty sure that my x values are unique and when I try the same code on a 10000 point dataset, there is no problem, however, when I run the same code on a 10 million point dataset I am getting 'cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful' error. The resulting "fit" becomes a 2000001 point array. I can provide more details if requested. Thank you.

The code:

```
fit5 <- smooth.spline(Time.s., Pressure.psi., cv = TRUE)
```

Again, I have a 10 million point dataset where there is a pressure value for every second. When I try this code with 10000 point dataset, it is fine, but when I try it with 10 million one, it throws the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same error arises for me when I switch from 1M to 10M line data sets. This works:

```
my_1M_dataset <- data.frame(timestamp = 1:1E6)
my_1M_dataset$y = sin(my_1M_dataset$timestamp/1E4)
smooth.spline(my_1M_dataset$timestamp, my_1M_dataset$y, cv = TRUE)

#Call:
#smooth.spline(x = my_1M_dataset$timestamp, y = my_1M_dataset$y, 
#    cv = TRUE)
# 
#Smoothing Parameter  spar= -1.37945  lambda= 3.609366e-17 (34 iterations)
#Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 217
#Penalized Criterion (RSS): 0.001138698
#PRESS(l.o.o. CV): 1.139195e-09
```

But this reproduces the warning in the OP.

```
my_10M_dataset <- data.frame(timestamp = 1:1E7)
my_10M_dataset$y = sin(my_10M_dataset$timestamp/1E4)
smooth.spline(my_10M_dataset$timestamp, my_10M_dataset$y, cv = TRUE)

#Call:
#smooth.spline(x = my_10M_dataset$timestamp, y = my_10M_dataset$y, 
#    cv = TRUE)
#
#Smoothing Parameter  spar= -0.3887605  lambda= 4.908993e-09 (17 iterations)
#Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 219.9931
#Penalized Criterion (RSS): 4964055
#PRESS(l.o.o. CV): 0.4964271
#Warning message:
#In smooth.spline(my_10M_dataset$timestamp, my_10M_dataset$y, cv = TRUE) :
# cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful
```

From the help for `smooth.spline`:

> The ‘generalized’ cross-validation method GCV will work correctly when
> there are duplicated points in x. However, it is ambiguous what
> leave-one-out cross-validation means with duplicated points, and the
> internal code uses an approximation that involves leaving out groups
> of duplicated points. cv = TRUE is best avoided in that case.

This suggests to me that the underlying code might use an approximation for x that might erroneously produce duplicates when x gets up to the 10M range. FWIW, the warning goes away when I remove `cv = TRUE`.

```
smooth.spline(my_10M_dataset$timestamp, my_10M_dataset$y)

#Call:
#smooth.spline(x = my_10M_dataset$timestamp, y = my_10M_dataset$y)
#
#Smoothing Parameter  spar= -0.4772853  lambda= 1.124464e-09 (16 iterations)
#Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 219.9984
#Penalized Criterion (RSS): 4964055
#GCV: 0.4964273
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Do the results change significantly when cv=False?